# GET requests object as Promise.all input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const { dailies, yesterdayDailies, members } = await Promise.all({
          dailies : api.get(`/daily/${currentDate}`),
          yesterdayDailies : api.get(`/daily/${currentGoalsDate}`),
          members : api.get(`/allMembers`)
        });

console.log(dailies, yesterdayDailies, members);
```

I need to pass an get requests object then de-structuring it to get their data, but I got:

```
TypeError: Argument of Promise.all is not iterable
```

It works passing an GET requests array, but I don't want to do that.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Well no, you need to pass an array (or other iterable) to make it work. *Why* don't you want to do that?

Comment: Alright I didn't know that is possible to de-structuring an array as @james answered below and I was accessing by index 0,1,2 .. by now it's solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure an array:

```
const [ 
  dailies, 
  yesterdayDailies,
  members
] = await Promise.all([
  api.get(`/daily/${currentDate}`),
  api.get(`/daily/${currentGoalsDate}`),
  api.get(`/allMembers`)     
]);
```

See [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)